# Simulation in c#

Tags: .net, directx, simulation

I'm a beginner C# developer, who is interested in learning 3d simulations. I have a project in mind
which involves a car crash simulation. Which technologies along with c#, would you recommend to accomplish the task? Right now I have managed DirectX 9.0 in mind. Any resource/place to start learning the technology would also be useful.

Comment: XNA is the supported graphics rendering platform for both 2D and 3D in C#, it superceded Managed DX 9.  It can also run on Xbox 360 hardware.

Comment: yes, i have put XNA and SLIMDX into consideration. Since i'm in the learning phase right now, I would prefer a technology that is easier to learn in terms of tutorials/resources available online. what are your views on this?

Comment: It doesn't get much easier than XNA. You'll need to think about a physics library too since XNAMath is really only for collision detection, and you'll need to manage the dynamics of the objects (velocity, momentum, angular momentum etc).

Answer (score 1):

Just off the bat but you would need skill up on your non-graphics knowledge first. Simulating the deformity of a metal plate is in the same category of math as simulating the heat equation. You're going to have to look up something called differential equations and technical details about the compression, stress, and shearing loads of metal plates. This is easily gained by taking a university level course in numerical methods and/or mechanical engineering. I would restrict myself to first simulating the crash in 2 dimensions.